# how to split transactions based on send and receive Json rpc bitcoin

Tags: json-rpc, bitcoin-cli

I am creating new wallet for bitcoin and want to know how we can get the separate list of send and receive transactions using JSON rpc.

I cant see any method for json rpc that give list of send and receive category

Comment: are you searching for  sendtoaddress rpc?

Comment: no , i am looking for the way to get list of sent and receive transactions ,listtransactions returning send and receive list , i want to get separate list of sent and recieve

Comment: you need to find it out through VOUT and VIN list

Comment: is that means there is no separate rpc call for getting the sent and receive for particular account label ?

Comment: listunspent : version 0.7 Returns array of unspent transaction inputs in the wallet. 
source : https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list

Comment: sorry but its not have any parameters that differentiate the accounts. i need a way so that on the basis of accounts label i have the sent and receive transactions list

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86589/discussion-between-pankaj-kumar-and-cryptoktm).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are looking for the `listtransactions` API call in combination with the `category` field.

First argument is for a specific account, use * to return all accounts.
2nd is how many you want to return.
3rd is if you want to skip transaction from the start.
4th argument is if you want to include watch-only addresses.

`$bitcoin->listtransactions("*", 100, 0, false);`

Example output (note the category field):

```
{
"result": [
    {
        "account": "",
        "address": "32NFcoB96ANoPnqycLH9WUd94o7bwRyq66",
        "category": "receive",
        "amount": 0.00385000,
        "label": "",
        "vout": 1,
        "confirmations": 24827,
        "blockhash": "000000000000000000250cffa73c2a08e64e53dab398ede3f38b1c30ae5c66ca",
        "blockindex": 317,
        "blocktime": 1529098309,
        "txid": "07b1d3fbc4d78d480d510264bb01bd390e81cda34dcb01e882e94adfa9355d10",
        "walletconflicts": [

        ],
        "time": 1529098115,
        "timereceived": 1529098115,
        "bip125-replaceable": "no"
    }
],
"error": null,
"id": null
}
```

Comment: sorry but how can i categorise all transactions ? With above results its mixed transactions of send and receive .Also i cant get the total count of all transactions

Comment: You need to filter the result yourself by looking at the category.

Comment: Andrew but i can understand that i have to filter result , but one thing i cant understand that how can i count the total transactions , as there is no count attribute return by the listransactions rpc call

Comment: Andrew can you please check if the above logic is correct or not

Comment: As achow mentions you need to add that yourself. Create a simple loop and then check to see if `category` equals `send` or `receive`, then output your data as you like.

Answer (score 0):

```
    from bitcoinrpc.authproxy import AuthServiceProxy, JSONRPCException
import logging
RPC_USER, RPC_PWD,URL,PORT="RPC_USER","RPC_PWD","URL","PORT"


CONN="http://%s:%s@%s:%s"%(RPC_USER, RPC_PWD,URL,PORT)
try:
    rpc_connection = AuthServiceProxy(CONN) 
    start=10
    end=0
    count=0 
    receive=[]
    send=[]
    while True:
        trans=rpc_connection.listtransactions("prologic",10,end)
        for tran in trans:                  
            if(tran['category'] == "receive"):
                receive.insert(0,tran)              
            else:
                send.insert(0,tran)
        if(len(trans) is 0):
            break
        else:
            end=end+10
            count=count+len(trans)


    all_trans={"total":count,"receive":{"count":len(receive),"trans":receive},"send":{"count":len(send),"trans":send}}
    print(all_trans)

except Exception as e:
    print (str(e))
```